# Helping to prevent Webpart Unable to Display

Tags: list-view

**[Final Update]**

Hopefully this post will be useful for others as they search webs for answers. I have noticed that *on some rare occasions* web parts do not load after a recent save. The webpart will have to be reloaded two or three times during the initial load after the save. After (usually) the second refresh, the correlation ID disappears permanently. So, why does this occur? It could be a multitude of reasons. In my case it has to do with the load time of the very complex xslt. I have altered my layout habits and have not had issues since. The following tactics have worked well for me:

1. break out and reference link css, xsl, js, anything that can be linked externally
2. Reduce template complexity by keeping a very close eye on recursive templates
3. turn off auto styling of css
4. turn off auto ID generation
5. If using any script blocks, check them to see if the code is being html encoded. I've run into situations where a CDATA block had to be decoded to remove unwanted characters.

[Original Question]
Kind of a strange question here that is leaving me stumped. Just the facts jack:

1. Users get the "Unable to display this Web Part...etc" message when opening a custom view (Listview).
2. This only happens for certain users or maybe certain workstations is more apt. I can open the view just fine from one workstation and not the other.
3. Opening the view and re-saving it without changing it gets it working again.
4. It gives a correlation ID but I am unable to find it in logs.
5. This problem will knock out all views for a specific list - I have to go re-save them all to get them working.

[UPDATED]

After some testing I found that when I load the list from outside our business network, it will cause the error internally. I proceed to save the page in SPD and it will work both internally and externally. The list works consistently externally.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error occurs when the XsltTransform takes too long to load. By increasing it, it should prevent this error from happening.

Go to the hosting server and open up PowerShell and type in the following:

```
$farm = Get-SPFarm
$farm.XsltTransformTimeOut = 10 // = 10 seconds. Set it to whatever you want.
$farm.Update()
```

AppPool recycle to make sure nothings cached and try loading the listviews again.

If the error still persists you're maybe looking at an Windows Update issue for Windows Server.

Comment: Thank you. I will add this to my testing sequence and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought: Build your Web Part on a test page, get it to display correctly, then export it and save it to your desktop. Then add it to a different page and see if remains stable.

This should be standard practice for all List View Web Parts, because saving the page unghosts the page. If you do your work on a test page that you then discard, you don't have to worry about unghosting your default.aspx page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you possibly elaborate on ghosting a bit? I dont think my understanding is accurate.

Comment: Sure thing. Pages, Lists, etc. in a site come from a template (Team Site, Blank Site). SharePoint uses the template info when showing "ghosted" or unmodified pages. If you customize a page (like adding a new Web Part Zone), your page is "unghosted" and SharePoint has to store your customization as additional info in the database. All this custom information can increase your database size over time, so it is better not to customize a page for no reason. You can click "Reset to site definition" under Site Settings to get rid of customizations. See also here: http://t.co/QbQT9xBKZD